# Add-in to allow user to save Office document directly to an owned/assigned Project Team Site

Tags: office365

I'm newbie for office O365 development. I'm trying to develop outlook OWA mail add-in using Visual studio 2013. I need to show the drop-down that should list all the projects which have been assigned for this particular user/mail-id in Project On-line. Also I need a "Save Document" button in this add-in hence the attachment(s) should upload to the selected project's document library once I clicked on "Save Document" button. How can I do this? Please help me in this regard.

If anyone having the similar kind of samples or links please help. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to just go with the standard [Custom pane](http://Custom%20pane%20Outlook%20add-ins) approach, with your UI appearing in the message body.  You could use a custom Ribbon button, but [Add-in commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/mt267546.aspx) are currently only supported in Outlook 2016 and not OWA/Outlook.com yet.

You can use the [item.AttachmentDetails](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/simple-types.html#AttachmentDetails) object to get the MIME content for each attachment to upload to SharePoint.